# Why do I keep getting some .cs file not found?

Tags: vb.net

I change debugging info to also debug files I do not write. I get this error

[image]

Basically it try to find .cs files in some f drive

I am pretty sure I never tell visual studio that the cs file should be in f drive. I have no idea why they look there.

What will be the easiest way to fix this problem?

Comment: You are trying to debug code written by Microsoft programmers and built on a Redmond build server.  On the F: drive.  Do focus on debugging your own code, Tuple does not have a bug and there is no practical way to change it.  Use Debug > Step Out to keep going.  And keep in mind that you are omitting important info to get the help you really need, change the debugger type to Mixed to diagnose unhandled .NET exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant comment is right.

Do you want to know from where is that path taken by VS?

It is in the metadata of the assembly. Open it with Ildasm or dotPeek, browse its metadata and you will find that path somewhere.